# How to GROUP BY several days in PostgreSQL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, select, count, group-by

The following code generates dates and counts records by day.

```
SELECT ts, COUNT(DISTINCT(user_id)) FROM 
( SELECT current_date + s.ts FROM generate_series(-20,0,1) AS s(ts) )
AS series(ts)
LEFT JOIN messages
ON messages.created_at::date = ts
GROUP BY ts
ORDER BY ts
```

The output looks like:

```
2011-07-07   0
2011-07-08   0
2011-07-09   0
2011-07-10   0
2011-07-11   0
2011-07-12   94
2011-07-13   56
2011-07-14   35
2011-07-15   56
2011-07-16   0
2011-07-17   13
```

How would you modify it to group by 2 days, so that the results overlap? Instead of counting the distinct user_id's for each day, it would count the distinct user_id's for each 2 day period.

This is different from summing the counts of the 2 days, as the user_id should be counted only once for each 2 day period.

Working in PostgreSQL 8.3.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT ts, COUNT(DISTINCT(user_id)) FROM 
( SELECT current_date + s.ts FROM generate_series(-20,0,1) AS s(ts) )
AS series(ts)
LEFT JOIN messages
ON messages.created_at::date between ts - 1 and ts -- JOIN on a range
GROUP BY ts
ORDER BY ts
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT ts, COUNT(DISTINCT(user_id)) 

FROM 

( SELECT current_date + s.ts 
  FROM generate_series(-20,0,2) AS s(ts) ) AS series(ts)

LEFT JOIN messages
ON messages.created_at::date = ts or messages.created_at::date = ts + 1

GROUP BY ts
ORDER BY ts
```